# Link PHP inside an echo tag

Tags: php, html, echo

I am having a problem with this code

```
 <?php
echo '<div class="post_note2">
<b>'.$lang['RENEW_SUCCESS'].'</b></div><br /><span class="orange"><b><a href="?view=main">HOME</a>|<a href="<?php echo $adurl; ?>">VIEW AD</a></b></span>';

        }
}?>
```

for some reason  when the VIEW AD link is clicked it doesn't build it properly and still contains the php code in the link rather than the link to the actual ad page. is it an issue with an echo in an echo ?
I'm sure this isn't quite difficult to solve but I have been trying for far to long on my own and cant get it.
Thanks, any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually had it right in the first part of your string. You can't have and echo statement inside of another echo statement. Use concatenation throughout your string:

```
<a href="' . $adurl . '"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two extra brackets at the end and php text inside your echo.

```
<?php
    echo '
        <div class="post_note2">
        <b>'.$lang['RENEW_SUCCESS'].'</b>
    </div>
    <br />
    <span class="orange">
        <b>
            <a href="?view=main">HOME</a> | <a href="' . $adurl . '">VIEW AD</a>
        </b>
    </span>';
?>
```

All fixed given that $adurl is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<?php echo $adurl; ?>
```

Should be

```
' . $adurl . '
```

i.e.

```
echo '<div class="post_note2"><b>'.$lang['RENEW_SUCCESS'].'</b></div><br /><span class="orange"><b><a href="?view=main">HOME</a>|<a href="'.$adurl.'>VIEW AD</a></b></span>';
```

Comment: @user2905791 - +1 perhaps (can i venture a tick)